# Dragging a UILabel within a UIView and maintaining it's new coordinates

Tags: ios, uiview, drag-and-drop, uipangesturerecognizer

So I have a `UILabel` on a `UIView` nib file and I am trying to give the user the ability to drag the label around and when they stop dragging the label stays there and if they try to drag it again they can.

I am able to drag the Label just fine using the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and when I stop dragging it the label stays where it is. The problem I am having is that when I attempt to drag it again the Label jumps back to the original starting position at the center of the `UIView`.

I understand that using the `UIPanGestureRecognizer.translation(in: UIVIew)` gives the original coordinates as `(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)` when the actual coordinates that the Label starts at are `(x: 150.0, y: 90.0)`.

```
@IBOutlet var cardView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var testLBL: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // trying to move the label
    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.wasDragged(gestureRecognizer:)))

    testLBL.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cardView.clipsToBounds = true

    testLBL.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)       
}
```

Below is the function that is used to handle the action, I have several other things I have tried commented out. I am also printing the current coordinates of the Label within the `cardView`

```
// function that helps drag the label around
func wasDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: cardView)

    //print(translation)

    // currently taking it from the original point each time you try to drag it

    testLBL.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width / 2 + translation.x, y: self.bounds.height / 2 + translation.y)


    //how you will know what position the label was moved to
    print(["x",self.testLBL.frame.origin.x,"y", self.testLBL.frame.origin.y])

    //let newTranslation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: cardView)

    //var coordinates = CGPoint(x: self.testLBL.frame.origin.x, y: self.testLBL.frame.origin.y)        
}
```

The `testLBL.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width / 2 + translation.x, y: self.bounds.height / 2 + translation.y)` operation is what allows the label to move and works find I just want it to not jump back to the middle of the `UIView` when I try to drag it again.

Any help is greatly appreciated because I am still pretty new at coding, Thank You!

Comment: you can use touch event methods for it...

Comment: I'm not really familiar with using them would it be possible to see an example of how I should use it?

Comment: @JimmyPayne check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747693/draggable-label-ios/37752721#37752721 from my own i hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

```
 // function that helps drag the label around
@objc
func wasDragged(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    let selectedLabel = gestureRecognizer.view!

    selectedLabel.center = CGPoint(x: selectedLabel.center.x + translation.x,
                                   y: selectedLabel.center.y + translation.y)
    gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)


    print(["1 x",self.testLbl.frame.origin.x,"y", self.testLbl.frame.origin.y])

}
```

Tested this code and it works, hope it helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.superview];
testLBL.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + translation.x, self.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];
```

apply it on swift you won't find that hard