# How to move textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have textfield.

```
let textFld = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: 
100, width: 200, height: 40))
textFld.placeholder = "Enter text here"
textFld.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
textFld.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
textFld.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
textFld.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
textFld.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
textFld.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.whileEditing;
textFld.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center

self.view.addSubview(textFld)
```

I want to move textfield with finger on screen. What do I need to do?
[image: Error]

[image: Bug]

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392104/drag-uibutton-without-it-shifting-to-center-swift-3/45392805#45392805 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001668/how-to-drag-certain-image-in-ios/45002245#45002245 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747693/draggable-label-ios/37752721#37752721

Comment: @ReinierMelian I get following errors: "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'layer'","Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'superview'",...

Comment: Which answer are you using?

Comment: @ReinierMelian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747693/draggable-label-ios/37752721#37752721

Comment: ok, can you add your implementation as edit in your question? to see what is wrong?

Comment: @ReinierMelian I edited question.

Comment: OK, I will provide an answer for you buddy

Comment: You are doing in a view controller something that has to be done in a UIView child class.

Comment: @algrid you are rigth

Comment: Do you want a click on the label to drag or Begin the click anywhere and the label will automatically "jump" to the finger touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a pan gesture recognizer you can do the trick here in this answer of my own I explain it a little further [Drag UIButton without it shifting to center [Swift 3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392104/drag-uibutton-without-it-shifting-to-center-swift-3/45392805#45392805)

**this code should work for you**

```
import UIKit

class DraggableUITextFieldViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

        var textFieldOrigin : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(textFieldDrag(pan:)))
            self.textField.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

            self.textField.layer.borderWidth = 1
            self.textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        }

        @objc func textFieldDrag(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            print("Being Dragged")
            if pan.state == .began {
                print("panIF")
                textFieldOrigin = pan.location(in: textField)
            }else {
                print("panELSE")
                let location = pan.location(in: view) // get pan location
                textField.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: location.x - textFieldOrigin.x, y: location.y - textFieldOrigin.y)
            }
        }
}
```

*Result*

[image]

Comment: which swift version are you using?

Comment: I have XCode 9.2

Comment: add "@objc" before func keyword @Vladislav

Comment: It works but leaves strange traces. I edited question again.

Comment: use my code, must work, for me work perfectly fine @Vladislav I had posted working on simulator